# Uncaught TypeError: c.querySelectorAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the vue.js application I'm working on, I suddenly get an error in Chrome inspector:

```
Uncaught TypeError: c.querySelectorAll is not a function
```

It always stops the execution. When I can continue and it doesn't seem to cause any additional problems. But I can't work like this if I have to hit continue several times after each click.

In the debugger I can see that `c` is a variable referencing a comment in the DOM. It affects different comments. But all comments have in common that they are inserted by *vue.js* a placeholders for dynamic elements.

On the stack trace, there is hardly any code of mine (see example below).

```
(anonymous) (content_script_bundle.js:16)
childList (async)
appendChild (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5711)
insert (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6036)
createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5980)
createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919)
addVnodes (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6100)
updateChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6227)
patchVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6313)
patch (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6476)
Vue._update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3942)
updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060)
get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473)
run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4548)
flushSchedulerQueue (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4304)
(anonymous) (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1980)
flushCallbacks (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1906)
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1933)
nextTick (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1990)
queueWatcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4396)
update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4538)
notify (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:730)
reactiveSetter (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1055)
(anonymous) (Workspace.vue?7337:142)
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) (Workspace.vue?7337:139)
loadPanel (Workspace.vue?7337:138)
mounted (Workspace.vue?7337:112)
invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
callHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4213)
insert (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3139)
invokeInsertHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6340)
patch (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6559)
Vue._update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3942)
updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060)
get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473)
run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4548)
flushSchedulerQueue (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4304)
(anonymous) (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1980)
flushCallbacks (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1906)
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1933)
nextTick (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1990)
queueWatcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4396)
update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4538)
notify (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:730)
reactiveSetter (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1055)
(anonymous) (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2555)
(anonymous) (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2554)
updateRoute (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2013)
(anonymous) (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1891)
(anonymous) (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2000)
step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1730)
step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1737)
runQueue (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1741)
(anonymous) (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1995)
step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1730)
(anonymous) (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1734)
(anonymous) (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1980)
(anonymous) (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1808)
iterator (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1959)
step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1733)
step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1737)
step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1737)
runQueue (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1741)
confirmTransition (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1988)
transitionTo (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1890)
push (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2200)
push (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2581)
handler (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:458)
invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179)
original._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6911)
```

What's the cause? How can I fix it? Is it related to the latest *vue.js* update?

Comment: No code to see?

Comment: I haven't managed to isolate any of my code that would be related to it... As you can see on the stack trace, it's all vue.js.

Comment: @RingoStore - Please post textual information (like stack traces) **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. (A picture coudl be an adjunct.) Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Do you know how to copy a stack trace from the Chrome's inspector as text? I couldn't find way to to it.

Comment: @RingoStore - Right-click the trace, "Copy stack trace"

Comment: Thanks. I have been right-clicking on the wrong lines of the stack trace.

Comment: @RingoStore - I was surprised clicking the header didn't offer that option too. :-) Don't forget to accept Codo's answer, now that it's been more than 15 minutes.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9335) tipped me off. It's not related to *vue.js* nor *webpack* nor *Angular*. It's caused by **Ghostery**.

Turn Ghostery off for your web page and the problem goes away.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I have Ghostery installed. I marked the site as trusted and no it's working. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hopefully someone's reported this to them!

Comment: Raised a ticket with them [here](https://ghostery.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/27587)

Comment: I am now unable to access my ticket with them... But I did get an email off them saying they are bringing a fix out in their next update.

[Ghostery Response](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/40743213/61032412-50b7a280-a3b9-11e9-900a-58068c7ceae1.png)

Answer (score 3):

> In the debugger I can see that c is a variable referencing a comment in the DOM

Well, that's the problem. [`Comment` nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment) don't have `querySelectorAll`. [`Text` nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) don't either. It doesn't make sense for them. Only [documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) and [`Element` nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) have the query functions.

Comment: I don't use `querySelectorAll`. So is it a `vue.js` bug?

Comment: @RingoStore - I doubt it. More likely some problem in the code using Vue.js.